# Android Studio 2.2 package names in Project view

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.2

After upgrading to AS 2.2, the packages shown in project view have "wrong" names.

Should be:
`com.something
    somethingelse
       Someclass.java`

But I see:
`com.something
    com.something.somethingelse
       Someclass.java`

Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: I have the same problem. I have reported the issue here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=223389

Comment: Oh so is because of DataBinding, good find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio 2.2.1 fixes this issue :

http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio221isnowavailable